# How to create a grading system in Python?

Tags: python

I have an assignment for school and one of the tasks is to display the grades that the students will be receiving. The grades are:

- A: 90% +
- B: 80% - 89%
- C: 70% - 79%
- D: 60% - 69%
- E: 50% - 59%

Here is some of the file, it's a comma-separated CSV file:

```
StudentName Score
Harrison    64
Jake    68
Jake    61
Hayley  86
```

I would like to know/get some guidance so I have a better understanding how to create the grade calculator.
I have spent ages trying to work it out but have had no hope.
My code:

```
def determine_grade(scores):
    if scores >= 90 and <= 100:
        return 'A'
    elif scores >= 80 and <= 89:
        return 'B'
    elif scores >= 70 and <= 79:
        return 'C'
    elif scores >= 60 and <= 69:
        return 'D'
    elif scores >= 50 and <= 59:
        return 'E'
    else:
        return 'F'
```

Comment: `if scores >= 90 and <= 100:` is syntactically incorrect. Use `if scores >= 90 and scores <= 100:` or `if 90 <= scores <= 100:`

Comment: A solution for later times when you have more experience. If you import `bisect` you could do `return 'FEDCBA'[bisect.bisect([50, 60, 70, 80, 90], score)]`. That's all.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) from Python's standard library for this purpose.

```
import bisect 

def determine_grade(scores, breakpoints=[50, 60, 70, 80, 90], grades='FEDCBA'):
    i = bisect.bisect(breakpoints, scores)
    return grades[i]
```

Comment: Try to improve your answer with some explanation. Especially that you are using an outside library that some people might not be familiar with. In this case, a link would also be very useful for example for further reference

Comment: This is basically a verbatim for one of the examples in `bisect` (built in library, not an outside library as you put it. https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#other-examples - note that this solution is much better when we have non-trivial dataset, eg if we have 5.000 different grades then if-else will simply not do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas and numpy to do it. Similar to this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Create a DataFrame

d = {                                                # Creating a dict for dataframe
    'StudentName':['Harrison','Jake','Jake','Hayley'],    
    'Score':[64,68,61,86]}
 
df = pd.DataFrame(d)   # converting dict to dataframe
                       # Keys get converted to column names and values to column values

#get grade by adding a column to the dataframe and apply np.where(), similar to a nested if


df['Grade'] = np.where((df.Score < 60 ), 
                  'F', np.where((df.Score >= 60) & (df.Score <= 69), 
                  'D', np.where((df.Score >= 70) & (df.Score <= 79), 
                  'C', np.where((df.Score >= 80) & (df.Score <= 89), 
                  'B', np.where((df.Score >= 90) & (df.Score <= 100), 
                  'A', 'No Marks')))))
print(df)

result:

    StudentName Score   Grade
0   Harrison    64      D
1   Jake        68      D
2   Jake        61      D
3   Hayley      86      B
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
def determine_grade(scores):
    if scores >= 90 and scores <= 100:
        return 'A'
    elif scores >= 80 and scores <= 89:
        return 'B'
    elif scores >= 70 and scores <= 79:
        return 'C'
    elif scores >= 60 and scores <= 69:
        return 'D'
    elif scores >= 50 and scores <= 59:
        return 'E'
    else:
        return 'F'
```

in every if u have to compare scores with values this is why `if scores >= 90 and  <= 100:` is incorrect, but after short editing it works

Answer (score 0):

For `scores >= 90 and <= 100` you can write `90 <= scores <= 100`

i don't know, if the score is a float or integer number. If the score is a float, your comparison isn't enough.

```
if scores >= 90 and <= 100:
        return 'A'
elif scores >= 80 and <= 89:
        return 'B'
```

What happen if the score is 89.99?

This is my solution. There are a GRADES_PATTERN. So you must not change your function, if something is changed.

```
GRADES_PATTERN = {'A':[90, float('inf')], 'B':[80, 90], 'C':[70, 80], 'D':[60, 70], 'E':[50, 60], 'F':[0, 50]}

def check_grade(score, pattern):
   for grade, score_range in pattern.iteritems():
      if score_range[0] <= score < score_range[1]:
          return grade
   raise Exception("score is out of pattern range")

print check_grade(89.99, GRADES_PATTERN)

students = {'Harrison':64, 'Jake': 68, 'Hayley':86}

for name, score in students.iteritems():
   print("Student {} hat score {} and grade {}".format(name, score, check_grade(score, GRADES_PATTERN)))
```

Comment: The scores are integer numbers, but thank you for your reply, I will check that out later.

Answer (score 0):

Another option...

If you didn't want an integer, you could change this for a float.

> ```
> grade = int(input("What was your score?"))
>
> if grade >=90 and grade <=100:
>     print("A*")
> elif grade >=80 and grade <=89:
>     print("A")
> elif grade >=70 and grade <=79:
>     print("B")
> else:
>     print("Unknown grade")
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You may just do this, noting the order of the `if` comparison.

```
def determine_grade(scores):
    if scores >= 90:
        return 'A'
    elif scores >= 80:
        return 'B'
    elif scores >= 70:
        return 'C'
    elif scores >= 60:
        return 'D'
    elif scores >= 50:
        return 'E'
    else:
        return 'F'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Score   Grade
# if > 1.0 error Bad score
# >= 0.9     A
# >= 0.8     B
# >= 0.7     C
# >= 0.6     D
# < 0.6      F

# ss (string score)
ss = input ("Enter your score: ")
# fs (float score)
try:
    fs = float (ss)
except:
    print("Error Bad score")
    quit()

#print(fs)
if fs >= 1.0:
    print("Error Bad Score")

if fs >= 0.9 :
    print ("A")
elif fs >= 0.8 :
    print ("B")
elif fs >= 0.7 :
    print ("C")
elif fs >= 0.6 :
    print ("D")
else:
    print ("F")
```

I try to solve it referenced by this great site: https://www.py4e.com/html3/03-conditional

Answer (score 0):

You could use this for the grading system but it doesn't put it into a nice array. Instead, it gives you a percentage and a grade letter.

```
def main():
    a = input("Enter amount of questions... ")
    b = input("Enter amount of questions correct... ")
    def calc(a, b):
        c = 100 / a
        d = c * b
        return d
    r = calc(int(a), int(b))
    print(f"Result: {int(r)}%")
    if int(r) < 80:
        print("Result is not passing, test will require Parent Signature.")
    t = 0
    if int(r) > 79:
        print("The test has passed!")
    if int(r) == 100 or int(r) > 92:
        print('Grade Letter: A')
        t += 1
    if int(r) > 91:
        if t != 0:
            return
        print('Grade Letter: A-')
        t += 1
    if int(r) > 90:
        if t != 0:
            return false
        print('Grade Letter: B+')
        t += 1
    if int(r) > 87:
        if t != 0:
            return false
        print('Grade Letter: B')
        t += 1
    if int(r) > 83:
        if t != 0:
            return false
        print('Grade Letter: B-')
        t += 1
    if int(r) > 80:
        if t != 0:
            return false
        print('Grade Letter: C+')
        t += 1
    if int(r) > 77:
        if t != 0:
            return false
        print('Grade Letter: C')
        t += 1
    if int(r) > 73:
        if t != 0:
            return false
        print('Grade Letter: C-')
        t += 1
    if int(r) > 70:
        if t != 0:
            return false
        print('Grade Letter: D+')
        t += 1
    if int(r) > 67:
        if t != 0:
            return false
        print('Grade Letter: D')
        t += 1
    if int(r) > 63:
        if t != 0:
            return false
        print('Grade Letter: D-')
    if int(r) > 60:
        if t != 0:
            return false
        print('Grade Letter: F')
        t += 1
    else:
        if t != 0:
            return false
        print('Grade Letter: F')
        t += 1
main()
```

Answer (score -2):

```
def determine_grade(scores):
    if scores >= 0 and <= 39:
        return 'U'
    elif scores >= 40 and <= 49:
        return 'D'
    elif scores >= 50 and <= 59:
        return 'C'
    elif scores >= 60 and <= 69:
        return 'B'
    elif scores >= 70 and <= 79:
        return 'A'
    else:
        return 'No Marks'
```

Comment: You shoulder refactor your answer, and use the correct syntax for code. Try to explain your answer as well instead of just posint raw code.