# How can I simplify repetitive if-elif statements in my grading system function?

Tags: python, if-statement, dry

The goal is to build a program to convert scores from a '0 to 1' system to an 'F to A' system:

- If `score >= 0.9` would print 'A'
- If `score >= 0.8` would print 'B'
- 0.7, C
- 0.6, D
- And any value below that point, print F

This is the way to build it and it works on the program, but it's somewhat repetitive:

```
if scr >= 0.9:
    print('A')
elif scr >= 0.8:
    print('B')
elif scr >= 0.7:
    print('C')
elif scr >= 0.6:
    print('D')
else:
    print('F')
```

I would like to know if there is a way to build a function so that the compound statements wouldn't
be as repetitive.

I'm a total beginner, but would something in the lines of :

```
def convertgrade(scr, numgrd, ltrgrd):
    if scr >= numgrd:
        return ltrgrd
    if scr < numgrd:
        return ltrgrd
```

be possible?

The intention here is that later we can call it by only passing the scr, numbergrade and letter grade as arguments:

```
convertgrade(scr, 0.9, 'A')
convertgrade(scr, 0.8, 'B')
convertgrade(scr, 0.7, 'C')
convertgrade(scr, 0.6, 'D')
convertgrade(scr, 0.6, 'F')
```

If it would be possible to pass fewer arguments, it would be even better.

Comment: Related: [Replacements for switch statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60208/4518341)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a grading system in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36716503/how-to-create-a-grading-system-in-python)

Answer (score 34):

You can use the [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) module to do a numeric table lookup:

```
from bisect import bisect 

def grade(score, breakpoints=(60, 70, 80, 90), grades='FDCBA'):
     i = bisect(breakpoints, score)
     return grades[i]

>>> [grade(score) for score in [33, 99, 77, 70, 89, 90, 100]]
['F', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'A']
```

Comment: I would like to have an additional +1 for the use `bisect`, which I find it used too rarely.

Comment: @norok2 I don't think a list of 4 elements is the place to start though. For such small lists a linear scan will likely be faster. Plus the use of a mutable default argument without any heads-up ;)

Comment: Sure, but it doesn't hurt and given the learning aspect of the question, I find it quite appropriate.

Comment: It is the example from the bisect module

Comment: @schwobaseggl even for such small lists bisect is faster.  On my laptop the bisect solution takes 1.2µs  and the loop takes 1.5µs

Comment: just missed the 5 minutes edit window...

Edit: I take it back: after some optimizations I got the loop solution to take 1.18µs

Answer (score 12):

You can do something along these lines:

```
# if used repeatedly, it's better to declare outside of function and reuse
# grades = list(zip('ABCD', (.9, .8, .7, .6)))

def grade(score):
    grades = zip('ABCD', (.9, .8, .7, .6))
    return next((grade for grade, limit in grades if score >= limit), 'F')

>>> grade(1)
'A'
>>> grade(0.85)
'B'
>>> grade(0.55)
'F'
```

This uses [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) with a default argument on a generator over the score-grade pairs created by [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip). It is virtually the exact equivalent of your loop approach.

Answer (score 6):

You could assign each grade a threshold value:

```
grades = {"A": 0.9, "B": 0.8, "C": 0.7, "D": 0.6, "E": 0.5}

def convert_grade(scr):
    for ltrgrd, numgrd in grades.items():
        if scr >= numgrd:
            return ltrgrd
    return "F"
```

Comment: Note, if you're using Python 3.6 or below, you should do `sorted(grades.items())` since dicts aren't guaranteed to be sorted.

Comment: This will not reliably work in all Python versions. Note that the order of a dict is not guaranteed. Also a `dict` is an unnecessarily heavy data structure, as it's the order that matters, and you are looking up by index (order) anyway, not by key.

Comment: Sure is not the most efficient, but it is arguably the most readable as all marks are written close to their threshold. I'd rather suggest replacing the dict with a tuple of pairs.

Comment: @schwobaseggl For this specific task, yeah, a list of tuples would be better than a dict, but if all this code were going in a module, the dict would allow you to lookup letter grade -> threshold.

Comment: @wjandrea If anything, you'd need to swap keys and values to allow something like `grades[int(score*10)/10.0]`, but then you should use `Decimal` as floats are notoriously ill-behaved dict keys.

Comment: You could simplify this by putting `"F": 0.0` in the dict.

Answer (score 5):

In this specific case you don't need external modules or generators. Some basic math is enough (and faster)!

```
grades = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "F"]

def convert_score(score):
    return grades[-max(int(score * 10) - 5, 0) - 1]

# Examples:
print(convert_grade(0.61)) # "D"
print(convert_grade(0.37)) # "F"
print(convert_grade(0.94)) # "A"
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `numpy.searchsorted`, which additionally gives you this nice option of processing multiple scores in a single call:

```py
import numpy as np

grades = np.array(['F', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A'])
thresholds = np.arange(0.6, 1, 0.1)

scores = np.array([0.75, 0.83, 0.34, 0.9])
grades[np.searchsorted(thresholds, scores)]  # output: ['C', 'B', 'F', 'A']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) from numpy library for multiple conditions:

```
>> x = np.array([0.9,0.8,0.7,0.6,0.5])

>> conditions  = [ x >= 0.9,  x >= 0.8, x >= 0.7, x >= 0.6]
>> choices     = ['A','B','C','D']

>> np.select(conditions, choices, default='F')
>> array(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F'], dtype='<U1')
```

Answer (score 2):

I've got a simple idea to solve this :

```
def convert_grade(numgrd):
    number = min(9, int(numgrd * 10))
    number = number if number >= 6 else 4
    return chr(74 - number)
```

Now,

```
print(convert_grade(.95))  # --> A 
print(convert_grade(.9))  # --> A
print(convert_grade(.4))  # --> F
print(convert_grade(.2))  # --> F
```

Answer (score 1):

You provided a simple case. However if your logic is getting more complicated, you may need a [rules engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_rules_engine) to handle the chaos.

You can try [Sauron Rule engine](https://github.com/blurg/sauron-engine) or find some Python rules engines from PYPI.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> grade = lambda score:'FFFFFFDCBAA'[int(score*100)//10]
>>> grade(0.8)
'B'
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

I am not adding much to the party, except for some timing on the most noteworthy solutions:

- using `bisect` (adapted from [@dawg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61030734/5218354))

```py
import bisect


def grade_bis(score, thresholds=(0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6), grades="ABCDF"):
    i = bisect.bisect(thresholds[::-1], score)
    return grades[-i - 1]
```

- using a generator-based linear search (adapted from [@user2390182's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61030707/5218354))

```py
def grade_gen(score, thresholds=(0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6), grades="ABCDF"):
    return next((
        grade
        for grade, threshold in zip(grades, thresholds)
        if score >= threshold), grades[-1])
```

- using a enumeration-based linear search (adapted from [@nico's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61030797/5218354))

```py
def grade_enu(score, thresholds=(0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6), grades="ABCDF"):
    for i, threshold in enumerate(thresholds):
        if score >= threshold:
            return grades[i]
    return grades[-1]
```

- using basic algebra -- although this does not generalize to arbitrary breakpoints, while the above do (based on [@RiccardoBucco's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61031874/5218354)):

```py
def grade_alg(score, grades="ABCDF"):
    return grades[-max(int(score * 10) - 5, 0) - 1]
```

- using a chain of `if`-`elif`-`else` (essentially, OP's approach, which also does not generalize):

```py
def grade_iff(score):
    if score >= 0.9:
        return "A"
    elif score >= 0.8:
        return "B"
    elif score >= 0.7:
        return "C"
    elif score >= 0.6:
        return "D"
    else:
        return "F"
```

They all give the same result:

```py
import random
random.seed(2)
scores = [round(random.random(), 2) for _ in range(10)]
print(scores)
# [0.96, 0.95, 0.06, 0.08, 0.84, 0.74, 0.67, 0.31, 0.61, 0.61]

funcs = grade_bis, grade_gen, grade_enu, grade_alg
for func in funcs:
    print(f"{func.__name__:>12}", list(map(func, scores)))
#    grade_bis ['A', 'A', 'F', 'F', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'D', 'D']
#    grade_gen ['A', 'A', 'F', 'F', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'D', 'D']
#    grade_enu ['A', 'A', 'F', 'F', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'D', 'D']
#    grade_alg ['A', 'A', 'F', 'F', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'D', 'D']
#    grade_iff ['A', 'A', 'F', 'F', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'D', 'D']
```

with the following timings (on `n = 100000` repetitions into a `list`):

```py
n = 100000
scores = [random.random() for _ in range(n)]
base = list(map(funcs[0], scores))
for func in funcs:
    res = list(map(func, scores))
    is_good = base == res
    print(f"{func.__name__:>12}  {is_good}  ", end="")
    %timeit -n 4 -r 4 list(map(func, scores))
#    grade_bis  True  4 loops, best of 4: 46.1 ms per loop
#    grade_gen  True  4 loops, best of 4: 96.6 ms per loop
#    grade_enu  True  4 loops, best of 4: 54.4 ms per loop
#    grade_alg  True  4 loops, best of 4: 47.3 ms per loop
#    grade_iff  True  4 loops, best of 4: 17.1 ms per loop
```

indicating that the OP's approach is the fastest by far, and, among those that can be generalized to arbitrary thresholds, the `bisect`-based approach is the fastest in the current settings.

---

## As a function of the number of thresholds

Given that the linear search should be faster than binary search for very small inputs, it is interesting both to see where is the break-even point and to confirm that this application of binary search grows sub-linearly (logarithmically).

To do so, a benchmark as a function of the number of thresholds is provided (excluding thos:

```py
import string


n = 1000
m = len(string.ascii_uppercase)
scores = [random.random() for _ in range(n)]

timings = {}
for i in range(2, m + 1):
    breakpoints = [round(1 - x / i, 2) for x in range(1, i)]
    grades = string.ascii_uppercase[:i]
    print(grades)
    timings[i] = []
    base = [funcs[0](score, breakpoints, grades) for score in scores]
    for func in funcs[:-2]:
        res = [func(score, breakpoints, grades) for score in scores]
        is_good = base == res
        timed = %timeit -r 16 -n 16 -q -o [func(score, breakpoints, grades) for score in scores]
        timing = timed.best * 1e3
        timings[i].append(timing if is_good else None)
        print(f"{func.__name__:>24}  {is_good}  {timing:10.3f} ms")
```

which can be plotted with the following:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.DataFrame(data=timings, index=[func.__name__ for func in funcs[:-2]]).transpose()
df.plot(marker='o', xlabel='Input size / #', ylabel='Best timing / µs', figsize=(6, 4))
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.patch.set_facecolor('white')
```

to produce:

[image: bm]

suggesting that the break-even point is around `5`, also confirming the linear growth of `grade_gen()` and `grade_enu()`, and the sub-linear growth of `grade_bis()`.

---

## NumPy-based approaches

Approaches that are capable of working with NumPy should be evaluated separately, as they take different inputs and are capable of processing arrays in a vectorized fashion.

Comment: Thanks for putting up some numbers on this!

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a recursive approach:

```
grade_mapping = list(zip((0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0), 'ABCDF'))
def get_grade(score, index = 0):
    if score >= grade_mapping[index][0]:
        return(grade_mapping[index][1])
    else:
        return(get_grade(score, index = index + 1))

>>> print([get_grade(score) for score in [0, 0.59, 0.6, 0.69, 0.79, 0.89, 0.9, 1]])
['F', 'F', 'D', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'A']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some more succinct and less understandable approaches:

The first solution requires the use of the floor function from the `math` library.

```py
from math import floor
def grade(mark):
    return ["D", "C", "B", "A"][min(floor(10 * mark - 6), 3)] if mark >= 0.6 else "F"
```

And if for some reason importing the `math` library is bothering you.  You could use a work around for the floor function:

```py
def grade(mark):
    return ["D", "C", "B", "A"][min(int(10 * mark - 6) // 1, 3)] if mark >= 0.6 else "F"
```

These are a bit complicated and I would advice against using them unless you understand what is going on.  They are specific solutions that take advantage of the fact that the increments in grades are 0.1 meaning that using an increment other than 0.1 would probably not work using this technique.  It also doesn't have an easy interface for mapping marks to grades.  A more general solution such as the one by dawg using bisect is probably more appropriate or schwobaseggl's very clean solution.  I'm not really sure why I'm posting this answer but it's just an attempt at solving the problem without any libraries (I'm not trying to say that using libraries is bad) in one line demonstrating the versatile nature of python.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dict.

**Code**

```
def grade(score):
    """Return a letter grade."""
    grades = {100: "A", 90: "A", 80: "B", 70: "C", 60: "D"}
    return grades.get((score // 10) * 10, "F")
```

**Demo**

```
[grade(scr) for scr in [100, 33, 95, 61, 77, 90, 89]]

# ['A', 'F', 'A', 'D', 'C', 'A', 'B']
```

If scores are actually between 0 and 1, first multiply 100, then lookup the score.

Answer (score 0):

Hope following might help:if scr >= 0.9:print('A')elif 0.9 > scr >= 0.8:print('B')elif 0.8 > scr >= 0.7:Print('C')elif 0.7 scr >= 0.6:print('D')else:print('F')